# php validation for html input type="date"

Tags: php, html

How am I supposed to validate this with PHP?

```
<html> 
<head><title></title></head>


<body>
<form>
<input type='date' name='currDate'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to validate? The data that's been entered or if it's been entered at all?

Comment: That It's been entered and I don't want to allow the user to enter a date that is before the today's date.

Comment: You're best to put that in your question then, give as much information as possible.

Comment: Also, what's the rest of your code looking like? Are you performing any PHP actions when the submit button is pressed? As it will tie into that. You just check if the date input has been set using 'isset'

Comment: I just want to forbide to select a date that is before the today's date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I can understand from your question, it seems like you want to get the value from this form and validate the value passed for **currData** in PHP server end.

If that's so you can try to execute the following on your PHP script to validate it.

```
if (DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_REQUEST['currDate']) !== FALSE){
  //Do proceed
}else{
  //Fail handle
}
```